# Is there a class of functions closed against differentiation besides elementary?

Tags: special-functions

Is there a finite set $P$ of non-elementary functions $f_n$ such that the derivative of any function $f$ from that set is not elementary, but expressible with functions from the same set $P$ plus elementary functions?

Comment: What do you mean by "expressible"? Compositions and algebraic operations? Partial inverses of the functions from your class (e.g. radicals)?

Comment: @Misha built from finite number of functions from P and elementary functions using arithmetic operations and composition.

Comment: OK, what functions do you regard as "elementary" (there is no consistent terminology here). Functions from where to where? (Real or complex.) For instance, would $P=\{erf\}$ satisfy you? Please, think through what you are really asking and update your question.

Comment: @Misha, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function The functions in P may be real or complex.

Comment: OK, if you use real functions and wiki definition, just take $P$ to consist of $\cos(x)$.

Comment: If I'm understanding the question right, let $g(x)$ an elementary function such that $f(x) = \int g(x)\ dx$ is not elementary. Then $P = \{f(x)\}$ works.

Comment: @Misha: $P$ needs to consist of nonelementary functions.

Comment: @v you're right, I will update the condition.

Comment: @rghthndsd: Accoring to OP's definition, $\cos(x)$ is nonelementary (for $x$ real), that's why I asked for his/her precise definition.

Comment: @rghthndsd I have added the requirement that the derivatives of those functions are not elementary.

Comment: @Misha This is not my understanding. When asked, Anixx linked to the wikipedia article which states such functions can be complex. Maybe I'm confused.

Comment: That's not a good update because you can just multiply rghthndsd's $f$ by $e^x$ and no number of differentiations will ever kill this non-elementary term. You can always solve a (system of) algebraic differential equation(s) of arbitrary complexity in non-elementary functions and your conditions imply that this is more or less the general description of it with the only interesting question being to describe all algebraic first-order differential systems that have no non-elementary solutions. That may be an interesting project per se, but I'd rather stay out of it :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $g$ be an elementary function whose indefinite integral $f$ is nonelementary, and set $P = \{\cos(t)f(t), \sin(t)f(t)\}$.

Answer (score 2):

- The Bessel functions, $\{J_\nu(x), K_\nu(x) | \nu\in\mathbb{Z}\}$
- Airy functions, $\{Ai(x), Ai^\prime(x)\}$, $\{Bi(x), Bi^\prime(x)\}$
- Complete elliptic integrals, $\{E(x), K(x)\}$

And also many other solution sets to classes of differential equations. You can also replace $x$ by any elementary function in these classes.

Comment: Are these classes have finite number of functions? It seems the derivatives of Bessel functions give Bessel functions with another index, and the derivative by index is not elementary. Complete elliptic integrals indeed seem to fit.

Comment: @Anixx For the Bessel functions, you can take any two consecutive indices, since they have recurrence identities. I.e., you can express the derivative of $I_\nu$ and $K_\nu$ in terms of $I_{\nu+1},K_{\nu+1}$ or $I_{\nu-1},K_{\nu-1}$ (in addition to $I_\nu,K_\nu$ themselves). That was unclear in my answer, sorry. The other two or three examples are already finite.